# Are there functions or packages in Mathematica to sort subsets in lex order, colex, revlex, etc.?

Tags: programming, sorting

I am looking for non-canonical sorts of lists. A function that would give:

```
Sort[X, "order type"]
```

With "order type" being [colex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colexicographical_order), revlex, etc.

Comment: I assume your X's are list of numbers. Define a predicate that handles lex. Then many other orders can be attained by multiplying by an appropriate matrix. For example revlex would use a matrix with 1's on the antidiagonal and 0's elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can effect any of the lex, colex, revlex, revcolex sorts by reversing elements and lists in the proper sequence.

*Edit:* My original answer used `Sort` and `Reverse`.  Since at the moment I cannot see why I did not use `SortBy[x, Reverse]` as [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) did in [an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41142/5) to a similar question I am modifying my answer to use the simpler method.

#### Reverse Lexicographic

The simplest variation, merely reverse the list after sorting:

```
Reverse @ Sort[x]
```

#### Colexicographical

Reverse the elements before sorting, using [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SortBy.html):

```
SortBy[x, {Reverse}]
```

#### Reverse Colexicographic

Simply reverse the entire list in addition to the steps for the colex sort:

```
Reverse @ SortBy[x, {Reverse}]
```

### Examples

A visualization function:

```
plot = ArrayPlot[SparseArray[List /@ # -> 1] & /@ #, ImageSize -> 80] &;
```

A random shuffle of subsets:

```
x = RandomSample @ Subsets[Range@7, {3}];
```

Our orderings:

```
lex      = Sort[x];
revlex   = Reverse @ Sort[x];
colex    = SortBy[x, {Reverse}];
revcolex = Reverse @ SortBy[x, {Reverse}];
```

A comparative graphic:

```
Row[plot /@ {lex, revcolex, colex, revlex}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version for reverse colexicographic sorting for numeric input:

```
SortBy[x, {-Reverse@# &}]

% == revcolex
```

> True