# Sorting lists element by element

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a problem regarding list sorting. Let's say I have a list of lists obtained using `Subsets[]`, of the form

```
{
{2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6},
{2, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6}
}
```

I would like to sort it element by element from the end, in descending order - so that all lists with `6` as the last element are first, sorted again in the same way by their second element, and sorted again by their first one, like so:

```
{
{4, 5, 6}, {3, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, 
{2, 3, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 4}
}
```

I am interested in a general solution as I need to apply this to lists of `n`-element permutations, not just triples like here.

I can easily sort them by a single element using `SortBy`, but I cannot grasp my head around a way to sort them recursively, step by step, `n` times. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This should work but I don't know much about sorting so don't ask :) `Composition[
  Reverse,
  Reverse /@ # &,
  Sort,
  Reverse /@ # &
  ][list]`

Comment: @Kuba Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use this:

```
Reverse @ SortBy[list, Reverse]
```

Comment: Embarrassingly I didn't use this method my answer to the question I marked as a duplicate.  I'm going to incorporate it into my answer there, with credit to you. +1

Comment: The performance of this code could be improved in the case of ties by using the stable sort syntax: `SortBy[list, {Reverse}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks for the reminder. For some reason the stable sort syntax just won't stick in my brain.

Answer (score 2):

I can't beat Simon's answer in simplicity, but an equivalent version, similar to Kuba's is:

```
With[{reverse = Reverse[#, 2] &}, Composition[Reverse, reverse, Sort, reverse]]@list
```

or even:

```
Composition[Reverse[#, {1, 2}] &, Sort, Reverse[#, 2] &]@list
```